# Do I need to worry about IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, backwards-compatibility

Im writing a website for a holiday cottage business and am having problems making the layout work in IE7. It works fine in IE8.

Will this be a problem? or should I spend a few hours trying to make it work?

I am looking for peoples' experiences based on previous web design work, and current knowledge of browser usage. Im not really after personal opinions.
Many thanks,

Comment: I am looking for peoples experiences based on previous web design work, and current knowledge of browser usage. Im not really after personal opinions.

Comment: If your boss insists on IE7 support or if you know you have significant numbers of users that are stuck with it, then obviously you need to support it. The rest of us can safely drop it. Most sites I know dropped it at least a couple of years ago already. Every OS that can run IE7 can also run IE8, so there's no technical reason for anyone to be unable to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that it depends on the audience for the site. If the site has existed in a previous form then see if it has some sort of analytics tracking so you can see what browsers were being used by the people who visited it.

At the very least put in a warning message letting people know that the site might be broken on older browsers and prompting them to upgrade. A quick example is this:

```
<!-- Prompt IE 7/6 users to upgrade to a newer browser. -->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. In order to experience this website properly, please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks :-) can you vote the question up please? some people didn't agree with it :-(

Comment: @Tommy Please read the "help" section so you will understand what kind of questions are welcome here. We have no personal problem with either you or your question.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of all people use the most up to date types of browser and even if they don't with ie they are most likely to have at least IE8 so I don't think you should worry

Comment: Thanks :-) can you vote the question up please? some people didn't agree with it :-(

Answer (score 1):

most of people will use IE8 or higher (if they are using IE at all ) ... so I don't think so

Comment: Thanks :-) can you vote the question up please? some people didn't agree with it :-(